# software-center update-manager both get segmentation fault

Tags: software-center, update-manager, segmentation-fault

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. After upgrading, neither software-center nor update-manager would run. I get a **segmentation fault** when launched from the console.
I can do `sudo apt-get update` without problem, but the upgrade does not work neither does the installation of any package i.e.,`sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get install emacs` simply returns the prompt back and nothing happens.

More exactly : `software-center` gives this :
`2012-01-30 16:07:17,144 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.em - INFO - EM's: 17 15 21 Segmentation fault` Nothing else happens then. With `update-manager: Segmentation fault` A window flashes and immediately goes away. With `sudo apt-get install emacs` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` nothing happens with either of these two commands. `sudo apt-get upgrade` works well though

Comment: Could you please add the exact error message to your question?

Comment: More exactly :

    `$ software-center` gives this : `2012-01-30 16:07:17,144 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.em - INFO - EM's: 17 15 21
    Segmentation fault`
Nothing else happen then.

With    `$ update-manager 
    Segmentation fault`
A window flashes and immediately goes away.

 With   `$ sudo apt-get install emacs` and `$ sudo apt-get upgrade` nothing happen with neither of this two last commands. (the `$sudo apt-get upgrade` works well)

François

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this thread on the Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=803215) *(for which the solution was originally found on [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=19563))*:

> **Question:**
>
> When I click System > Administration > Update Manager it comes up (grayed out) and the small "Starting Update Manager" window comes up but when the bar is half filled it disappears.
>
> **Answer:**
>
> According to a forum thread from the archive, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=19563, you should be able to fix the problem by issuing the following command from a terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
> ```

Comment: Most welcome :)

Comment: Just had the same problem but /var/cache/apt has no *.bin files in it. Any other suggestions?