# Software Center Won't start

Tags: software-center

For a few days now, my Ubuntu Software Center won't start. Ubuntu One also won't connect (not sure if that's related).

When I try launching Software Center from Dash, nothing happens. If I try running 'software-center' from terminal, I get this error message:

```
2012-03-19 10:26:43,316 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.em - INFO - EM's: 17 15 21
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 149, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app import SoftwareCenterAppGtk3
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 82, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.panes.installedpane import InstalledPane
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/installedpane.py", line 43, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.backend.oneconfhandler import get_oneconf_handler
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/oneconfhandler.py", line 25, in <module>
    from softwarecenter.backend.restfulclient import get_ubuntu_sso_backend
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/restfulclient.py", line 36, in <module>
    from lazr.restfulclient.resource import ServiceRoot
ImportError: No module named restfulclient.resource
```

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 AMD64

EDIT:

It started happening after I install all the dependencies needed to setup an environment to work on the Ubuntu Summit website. I'm assuming something I installed must not have played nice with the rest of my system.

Comment: file bug report http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug

Comment: Please, could you post the output of `dpkg -S /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/restfulclient.py`? I cannot find that file in the Ubuntu archives.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini This is what I get: software-center: /usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/restfulclient.py

Comment: what version of Ubuntu? What version of Software Center?

Comment: @cprofitt Ubuntu 11.10. Software Center, umm whichever is suppose to be in 11.10 I guess.

Comment: See this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/99869/software-center-update-manager-both-get-segmentation-fault

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command to reinstall software center.

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center

If this does not work try:

> sudo apt-get install python-simplejson

Comment: No go. Wasn't fixed :/

Comment: Python Simplejson is already installed as well. Not sure what else to do. Neither this nor Ubuntu One works anymore, even after I followed a few guides on restoring them. I might just wait till my 12.04 fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

Please update your system in a terminal with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

If you get any faults there link those in your question, if this solves your issue then flag this to the moderators, if nothing happened drop a comment.

Comment: I had the same issue, it was resolved with a updated system and I reinstalled the USC.

Comment: There are no problems with updating. I followed suggestions in all the answers above to no avail as well.

Comment: You should file a bug for this then. You can do so by opening a terminal and typing `ubuntu-bug software-center`.

Answer (score 0):

No clue if this will help you, but the same thing happened to me after messing with `python-pip`, `python-setuptools` and `python-virtualenv`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pkg-resources
```

fixed it for me.

Actually looking at your traceback says it all. Run this...

```
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-lazr.restfulclient
```

This is a dependency of software-center. If you look up software-center [online](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/software-center) or in synaptic, you'll see it's required. But your traceback is saying it can't find that module.

Comment: I got excited when I saw your answer because it looks like that would work but sadly it didn't. 22 days till 12.04. It better work with a fresh install of Precise.

Comment: have you tried `$sudo apt-get install synaptic` to see if there are any broken dependencies? Synaptic is a very useful gui for installing and managing packages. You might be fine with Synaptic until Precise comes out.