# How can I fix errors relating to the launch of the Software Center?

Tags: 12.04, software-center

My Ubuntu Software Center is will not launch.  I have read several related question and I have tried various suggestions from Ask Ubuntu including [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114267/software-center-wont-start), but all attempts return the same error messages.  I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-pkg-resources
```

All attempts provide the following errors:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:  
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-problem-report_2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/python-apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1_all.deb  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apport_2.0.1-0ubuntu15.1_all.deb  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets_0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu7_all.deb  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-aptdaemon.pkcompat_0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu7_all.deb  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-aptdaemon_0.43+bzr805-0ubuntu7_all.deb  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/software-center_5.2.6_all.deb
```

How do I correct these errors and get my system functioning properly?

---

In response to Lucio's comment:

Running the following two lines of code produced the same errors.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Continuing with the help file, I ran:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and received the following errors:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pkg-resources  
 python-aptdaemon  
 python-aptdaemon.pkcompat  
 apport-gtk  
 software-center  
 python-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets  
 gedit-plugins  
 python-problem-report  
 aptdaemon  
 update-notifier-common  
 python-apport  
 flashplugin-installer  
 apport
```

Finally, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

but this, again, provided the original errors.

I was installing Python 3.3 to use as the default vice Python2.7. Is any of this (from `/usr/bin`) creating my problem?

```
*-rwxr-xr-x  1 root         root             4124 Apr 17  2012 pyclean  
*-rwxr-xr-x  1 root         root            11933 Apr 17  2012 pycompile  
*lrwxrwxrwx  1 root         root                8 Aug 14 18:02 pydoc -> pydoc2.7  
*-rwxr-xr-x  1 root         root               79 Aug  1 01:40 pydoc2.7  
*lrwxrwxrwx  1 root         root               12 Aug 14 18:02 pygettext -> pygettext2.7  
*-rwxr-xr-x  1 root         root            22103 Aug  1 01:40 pygettext2.7  
*-rwxr-xr-x  1 root         root              217 Mar  9  2012 pyhtmlizer  
*lrwxrwxrwx  1 root         root               28 Dec 24 01:51 python -> /usr/bin/Python-3.3.0/python  
*lrwxrwxrwx  1 root         root                9 Aug 14 18:02 python2 -> python2.7  
*-rwxr-xr-x  1 root         root          2989480 Aug  1 01:40 python2.7  
*drwxr-xr-x 16 inigomontoya inigomontoya     4096 Dec 24 01:42 Python-3.3.0  
*-rw-r--r--  1 root         root         16327785 Sep 29 05:15 Python-3.3.0.tgz  
*lrwxrwxrwx  1 root         root               29 Aug 14 18:02 pyversions -> ../share/python/pyversions.py
```

Comment: The problem is not the SC, but the mentioned packages. You should enter the first two commands of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/148389/62483). Notify the result please.

Comment: I followed the tutorial but the result was the same.  I updated my question with more details.

Comment: Please also paste large blocks of code into this [official Ubuntu tool](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and attach it into your question where acceptable. Thanks :)

Comment: @user117091 Run the following commands. `sudo rm -r /var/cache/apt/archives` and then `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`

Comment: The first line kicked me back to a prompt and when I ran the second line I received the message: `E: Could not open lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to lock the download directory`

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If the version of python is the issue, can you please post the output of `sudo update-alternatives --config python`? If it shows python 3.3 as the default, change it to python 2.7 and then re-install the software-center, otherwise the version of python does not seem to be the root-cause.

Comment: The output is: `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python.`