# Software Center will not start

Tags: software-center, 64-bit

I tried to launch Ubuntu Software Center to day, but it didn't start, so I tried     launching it through the terminal, giving this error:

```
2013-04-19 10:21:51,505 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2013-04-19 10:21:51,527 - softwarecenter.db.database - INFO - open() database: path=None use_axi=True use_agent=True
2013-04-19 10:21:51,755 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py', 410, '_introspect_error_handler')'
2013-04-19 10:21:51,754 - dbus.proxies - ERROR - Introspect error on com.ubuntu.sso:/com/ubuntu/sso/credentials: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/lib/ubuntu-sso-client/ubuntu-sso-login exited with status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 337, in __init__
    self.icons)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/appmanager.py", line 66, in __init__
    self.oauth_token = helper.find_oauth_token_sync()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/ubuntusso.py", line 139, in find_oauth_token_sync
    sso.find_credentials()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/login_impl/login_sso.py", line 75, in find_credentials
    self.proxy.find_credentials(self.appname, self._get_params())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__         **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process /usr/lib/ubuntu-sso-client/ubuntu-sso-login exited with status 1
```

This was after I installed LXDE, and started using that instead of Unity, I don't think that's related, but I thought you should know.

Running Ubuntu 12.10 64bit

Comment: This is a bug report, which is off-topic for Ask Ubuntu, as noted in the FAQ.

Comment: Is there an open bug report for this already? This issue has been posted on Ask Ubuntu many times with no apparent solution yet.

Comment: Does it work when you switch back to unity? (that is to say, are you *sure* it's unrelated to lxde..?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Software Center Won't start](http://askubuntu.com/questions/114267/software-center-wont-start)